# Sorting by sql_attr_float in Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, indexing, sphinx

I just added price and sale_price attributes to my indexes in sphinx and it seemed like it was sorting just fine using, `$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED,'price desc');`, however after a few pages the price shot back up again.

For instance, page one showed prices $1,000 - $800, page two showed prices $800 - $500, page three showed prices $500 - $200, then out of nowhere page four showed $300 - $100 or some random assortment of prices.

I'm wondering if sphinx is possibly still sorting by weight event though I haven't explicitly told it to... Does that sound like the problem?

I'm open to indulging any other ideas as well. Also, I definitely reindexed and rotated all indices and sphinx is not returning any errors.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here are all the options I'm currently using: (update for @barryhunter)

```
$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN);
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED,'price desc');
$s->SetFilter("is_private", array(0));
$s->SetFilter("is_deleted", array(0));
$s->SetFilter("site_type", array(1));
$s->SetLimits($start, $count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was suggested in a comment by @barryhunter!

I added a new integer col to mysql called `sort_price` and filled it with `(price * 100)`.
I then added that col as `sql_attr_uint` in sphinx and the sorting works perfecto!!

```
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED,'sort_price desc');
```

Thanks Barry :)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, are you using a Group-By?

If so, then `SetSortMode` does NOT set the order of the final results. The third param to `setGroupBy` does *instead*.

read the documentation on Group by to see how the two sort orders work.

Otherwise what column type do you store the price? Maybe its not getting converted to sphinxes float type correctly.

Comment: updated my question with all options in use. No group by currently. :(

Comment: also mysql col type for price and sale_price: DECIMAL(10,2)

Comment: I dont know then. My only suggestion is to try using a sphinx integer attribute (eg multiply your price by 100 to get a interger) - not sure why, but it might be mroe relable (and quicker) than using float.

Comment: that's not a bad idea.